# Is there any way I can maintain ordering (based on an attribute not by the message time) in a single partition of a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say, this is a one-partition topic, and while consuming the message I want to read it in a sequence based on one of the attributes (Let's assume attr1) in the message.

1. Message 1 ('attr1'="01") was posted to that partition at 9:50 pm.
2. Message 2 ('attr1'="03") was posted to that partition at 9:55 pm.
3. Message 3 ('attr1'="02") was posted to that partition at 10:55 pm.

I want to consume it in the sequence based on the attr1 value, so Message1, Message3, and Message2 should be my consuming order.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible.
A fundamental thing to remember about Kafka is Offset. When you write a message to a partition - its always gets incremental offset.

In your example, if

message 1 gets offset 1

message 2 will get offset 2

message 3 will get offset 3

On the consumer side as well, message will always be read in sequence of increasing offsets. You can specify your consumer to start reading from a particular offset, but once it starts reading the message, the consumer will always get message in the sequence of increasing offset.

Comment: It's definitely "possible". You just need to read all data from the topic before "processing it"

Comment: The question is wether it be "consumed" from kafka attribute wise, which is not possible. Reading everything and then sorting is a user implementation, that is obviously possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative tools such as ksqlDB or Kafka Streams to first read the entire topic, then sort based on custom attributes, or use `Punctuator` class to delay processing based on time windows.

Otherwise, Kafka Connect can dump to a database, where you can query/sort based on columns/fields/attributes, etc.